# jQuery Accordion struck behavior on expand

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery UI plugin for Accordion

And i noticed that On clicking any tab of accordion, the expand behavior is not smooth it behaves as struck and release.

Can any one tell me what could be wrong and how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was having same issue, after breaking my head for long time, I noticed that, it si because of css height property.

I had height : auto !important;

`!important` was creating that problem
remove it, should fix your problem.